# Android navigation drawer with custom animation for underlying content

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

Good day fellow developers, 
I am new in android development, but I have been given quite a challenging task :)

My question is, is it possible to create a navigation drawer with a semi-open door-like effect for the underlying content? (don't know how the effect is called, please look at the attached image, sorry for the blur)

If yes, could you give me a few tips on how to create such an effect or where should I look into? I know how to make a navigation drawer ) My problem is the animation effect..

Thank you for your time.

image:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Vpox.jpg

Comment: Extend navigation drawer class and play around. There is no specific way.

Comment: there is some custom code in this ;ink http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21840916/blur-background-of-navigation-drawer?rq=1

Comment: Thank you both for the answers. I will definitely look into that code.

Comment: i extended the navigation drawer class and tried to do something i wnted but it is not working. is there any link where i could take nay reference