# Blur background of Navigation Drawer Opening From Right to Left

Tags: android, navigation-drawer, android-navigationview

I am referring [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21840916/blur-background-of-navigation-drawer) Stack Overflow Question to achieve blurry background in the `NavigationView` with the drawer opening from the Right. The problem is with Right gravity of the `BlurAndDimView`.

When I set the gravity of the `NavigationView` to right the drawer works properly but the blurry view stays still in the Left.
When I set the Gravity of the `BlurAndDimView` right it went in the Centre and the drawer disappeared.

I Also tried to alter the methods `public void handleScroll(float xOffset)`  and `public void setImage(Bitmap bmp, int downSampling)` of the `BlurAndDimView` class as follows-

```
public void handleScroll(float xOffset) {
        if (image != null) {
            rectSrc.left = getWidth()-(int) (image.getWidth() * xOffset);
            rectDst.left = rectSrc.left * downSampling;
            rectRest.right = rectDst.left;

            /*rectSrc.right = (int) (image.getWidth() * xOffset);
            rectDst.right = rectSrc.right * downSampling;
            rectRest.left = rectDst.right;*/

            dimPaint.setAlpha((int) (xOffset * MAX_DIM_ALPHA));
            invalidate();
        }
    }

    public void setImage(Bitmap bmp, int downSampling) {
        Bitmap cropped = Bitmap.createBitmap(bmp, 0, 0, menuWidth / downSampling, getHeight() / downSampling);
        this.image = Blur.fastblur(getContext(), cropped, BLUR_RADIUS);
        /*rectSrc = new Rect(0, 0, bmp.getWidth(), bmp.getHeight());
        rectDst = new Rect(0, 0, menuWidth, getHeight());
        rectRest = new Rect(menuWidth, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());*/

        rectSrc = new Rect(0, 0, bmp.getWidth(), bmp.getHeight());
        rectDst = new Rect(getWidth() - menuWidth, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
        rectRest = new Rect(0, 0, getWidth() - menuWidth, getHeight());

        this.downSampling = downSampling;
        invalidate();
    }
```

But It didn't work . Drawer Disappeared!
Thanks for the help in advance.