# How to make blurred side bar like as given below snapshot?

Tags: android, sidebar, blur

I tried many methods to get blur side menu bar but no correct way is found. I have been used picasso lib, Blurry lib and other methods.

[image: I want this]

Comment: This seems semi-transparent instead of blurred. Just set alpha on the background of the layout like android:background="#AAFFFFFF"

Comment: sir i also tried with alpha it becomes translucent with alpha color not seems like blur .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either use the `android:background` property with `alpha` value.

**OR**

you can use this library to get a blurred nav drawer :

- [Blur Navigation Drawer](https://github.com/charbgr/BlurNavigationDrawer)

**OR**

you can try something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21840916/blur-background-of-navigation-drawer)

Answer (score 0):

Add these 2 attributes to the Parent layout in which you wanna add the blur:

```
android:backgroundTintMode="multiply"
android:backgroundTint="#dddddd"
```

Replace `#dddddd` with your own color, experiment which one looks best.

Answer (score 0):

Try below examples:

[Check this](https://futurestud.io/blog/how-to-blur-images-efficiently-with-androids-renderscript)

[this one also](http://android-er.blogspot.in/2015/02/create-blur-bitmap-using-renderscript.html)