# Android DrawerLayout blur background

Tags: android, blur, drawerlayout

I would like to blur the background of the content pane when the DrawerLayout is open. I noticed that there is the ability to change the dim color by setting setScrimColor but I would like to blur the background. Is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

The process involves the following stages:

- Get a snapshot of the whole drawer layout.
- Crop it to the exact size of your menu.
- Downscale it quite a bit (a factor of 8 is pretty good).
- Blur that image.
- Have a custom view that displays part of an image right behind of
  where your menu will appear.

  - As you slide the drawer show a larger part of that image.

Please refer this answer

[Blur background of Navigation Drawer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21840916/blur-background-of-navigation-drawer/22229686#22229686)

Or you can use one of these libraries

[EtsyBlur](https://github.com/Manabu-GT/EtsyBlur)

[BlurNavigationDrawer](https://github.com/charbgr/BlurNavigationDrawer)

[BlurEffectForAndroidDesign](https://github.com/PomepuyN/BlurEffectForAndroidDesign)

Answer (score 0):

Check out this library: [Blurry](https://github.com/wasabeef/Blurry). it takes a `View` or a `Bitmap`, blurs it and casts it to a `ViewGroup` or an `ImageView`. So just run `Blurry.with(context).capture(parentView).into(parentView);` whenever the drawer is opened.
Where `parentView` is the container that holds everything.